# Require can't find the path

Tags: php, jquery, google-app-engine, require

I'm new to both PHP and GAE, so apologies in advance for the simple question.  I can't get my main.php file to find a required file.  My hunch is that my app.yaml isn't configured correctly, but I've never gotten a require statement to work so it could be anything.

My app.yaml file:

```
application: myapp
version: 1
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:

- url: /js
  static_dir: js

- url: /css
  static_dir: css

- url: /examples
  static_dir: examples
  application_readable: true

- url: /handler
  script: main.php

- url: .*
  script: main.html
```

Client-side html which calls main.php:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="../js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/jquery.mousewheel-min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/jquery.terminal-min.js"></script>
    <link href="../css/jquery.terminal.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('body').terminal("handler", {
            //login: true,
            greetings: "",
            onBlur: function() {
                // the height of the body is only 2 lines initialy
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
  </head>
<body>
</body>
```

"handler" points to the main.php script, and it works.  Main.php:

```
<?php
    require(dirname(__FILE__).'/examples/json_rpc.php');
  //require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/examples/json_rpc.php');
  //require 'json_rpc.php';
  class Server {
    public function test($message) {
      return "you send " . $message;
    }
  }

  handle_json_rpc(new Server());
  ?>
```

I've tried various permutations of paths, relocating json_rpc.php to be in the same directory as main.php, etc, but nothing has worked so far.  Note that when I insert the code in json_rpc.php into main.php, everything works as expected, so I think it's purely a path issue.  The error is a standard 'failed to open stream".  Many thanks in advance!

Comment: The `app.yaml` appears fine. What is the result of `dirname(__FILE__) . '/examples/json_rpc.php'`? Also, am I correct in understanding that you wish to have a script executing from `/handler` require a script that's `application_readable` from a neighboring directory `/examples`?